# SASS: randomly pick background-image from a list

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I need to output this:

```
#footer-widgets .container .row {
    background-image: url("RANDOMLY PICKED");
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

... and there should be a list with 4 or 5 links to the actual background-images (http://domain.com/blablabla/image.png) to pick from. How can I do this with SASS?

Comment: You do understand that Sass is compiled first and only the compiled CSS sent to the browser, right?  You could have the background image randomly generated on each compile, but you can't have it be random per page view.

Comment: Sass compiles to css. I've never heard of random urls in css as its style not logic. The best solution (if you are looking for a per-view random selection) would be http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/randomize-background-image/. If you want a per-compile or per-page random image you probably need to go back and have a looks at the design of your site and messaging to make sure what you want is really an image randomly selected.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The most recent version of Sass [(v3.3.0)](http://rubygems.org/gems/sass/) adds a new `random` function. If you mix that with a list of images (and a wee bit of variable interpolation), you will have CSS with a randomly selected background image every time Sass is compiled.  Example:

```
$imgKey: random(5);

$list: apple, banana, cherry, durian, eggplant;
$nth: nth($list, $imgKey);

body {
  background-image: "/images/#{$nth}.jpg";
}
```

Live example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/8966210

As above, the random value will only change when the **Sass is compiled**, which won't necessarily be every time your page is visited.

Comment: Thanks, will try soon. So when does it get compiled?

Comment: Every time you change the Sass, on the live example or if you're doing `sass watch`.

Comment: If anyone else was wondering what `nth` does, it's an inbuilt: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the value 5, you can use the [`length`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#length-instance_method) function. And if you're using a map instead of a list, you can use [`map-values`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_values-instance_method) to convert it to a list first.