# Sass: Pick randomly a variable

Tags: css, list, random, colors, sass

There's a [question answered more than one year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739839/sass-randomly-pick-background-image-from-a-list) where the main topic is random in Sass. Well, in that question the person who asks is looking for a method to pick randomly a word from a list. I want to do the same, but using variables instead of using words. Modifying the same answer, I have tried:

```
body { color: ${$nth}; }

$imgKey: random(5);
$list: blue, red, yellow, orange, pink;
$nth: nth($list, $imgKey);
```

this:

```
body { color: $nth; }

$imgKey: random(5);
$list: blue, red, yellow, orange, pink;
$nth: nth(${$list}, $imgKey);
```

and this:

```
body { color: $nth; }

$imgKey: random(5);
$list: $blue, $red, $yellow, $orange, $pink;
$nth: nth($list, $imgKey);
```

But all these options give me, as a result, an error. Can you help me?

Comment: I don't even know what to say here, you've got all sorts of syntax errors here (using language constructs that don't exist), trying to use variables that don't exist yet, etc.  It's like you didn't even read the answer in that question you linked to.

Comment: Variables are declared, but here don't appear. They are `$blue`, `$red`, `$yellow`, `$orange` and `$pink`, all with its value.